# render a remote pdf inside new pdf with prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, pdf-generation, prawn

I am using Prawn to generate PDFs. Prawn can load images [very readily](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/manual.pdf), but I need to be able to render images or other PDFs inside the PDFs I'm generating with Prawn.

Has anyone tried to do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have to just merge the external PDF together with the generated one

[How do you combine PDFs in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499563/how-do-you-combine-pdfs-in-ruby)