# Merging Large number of PDFs Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I was trying to use Prawn to merge PDF's together. 
However I noticed that memory consumption increases linearly with number of PDF's and my pc also shooted at 100% CPU utilization.
My problem is it goes out of memory when trying to merge around 10000 PDF's of size 40kb.

[I was using this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14284886/2472056) sample code for merging PDF's together.

I tried integrating solution of [this issue](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/509) with my gem but still no success.

The question of merging PDF together is quite moot, but I was not able to find any working ruby gems for this issue. (pdf-merger was also facing same issues).

Is there any way I can optimize the code, or maybe the merged file goes directly into disk rather than into memory. (or other suggestions which are actually optimized for my pdf generation/merging requirements)

Comment: Would a pdf file with 10000 or more pages be readable (openable)? I think the whole idea of creating such huge pdf is wrong in the first place.

Comment: Yes I am able to open and read a 10000 page PDF file which is generated. But sometimes while generation, prawn throws an out of memory error

Comment: Even so, I think it is a wrong idea to do that.

Comment: You could try to use external utilities, like `pdftk`,`pdfunite`, `poppler`, etc.

Comment: i agree with @sawa that such a huge PDF is not a good idea from a user experience point of view - that being said, i've used pdftk in the past and didn't like it so much. I would recommend to build something around Qpdf

Comment: I agree that this is not a very good idea but it is a rigid requirement. Please give some suggestions/alternatives if possible.